# Android - get touched view's ID using AspectJ

Tags: android, view, aspectj

I'm new to AspectJ and I'm trying to write "user input recorder", which should record touched view's ID's.

My first idea is to try to pointcut View's onTouchEvent method, is it possible?
Is there any other/better approach to this task?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  Checkout this guys article:  http://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/

Also check out this guys Gradle plugin and example projects:  https://github.com/leolin310148/GradleAndroidAspectJPlugin

Comment: Thank you for answer, :) but I've used UiAutomation framework for this task.
The con for this is requirement of API 18.

Comment: Sure, UiAutomation will click it for you, but that's different than recording each time the listener is invoked.